# UIScrollView not updating after calling setContentSize in viewDidLoad, but does when called from a button

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, autolayout

I have a `ViewController` with a `UIScrollView` that contains a `View` that contains variable-sized content.

```
- ViewController
    -ScrollView
        -View
            -label1
            -label2
            - ...
```

When the controller's `viewDidLoad` is called, I set the `UIScrollView`'s content size to the appropriate height, but the view doesn't scroll. If I call the same line from an action on a button, it does update the `contentSize` and scrolls correctly. I am using `autolayout`. Any idea why and how to fix it?

The view won't scroll:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,500)];
}
```

The view will scroll correctly:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender 
{
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,500)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewDidAppear also Guarantees that your view has been loaded and initialized But viewdidAppear fires after viewDidLayoutSubviews. if you do large coding in ViewDidLoad Realted to UI your ViewController delayed in display

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100,500)];
}
```

Comment: a little correction, `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` , and `viewDidLoad` also gurantees view is loaded and initialized.  But viewdidAppear fires after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Wow thanks that fixed it, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Keeping viewDidLoad to a minimum seems like good practice too. I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me (5 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set content size in `viewDidLoad`. Do it in `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

- ViewController
  -ScrollView
      -View
          -label1
          -label2

First ScrollView add new contraints and next label1 and label2 add contraints then final View view can add contraints.